# Flyway stuck when cleaning database (Postgres 11)

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, flyway

our application contains tests which are can't simple rollback. So we decide use flyway's java API for it. We added this method into test:

```
@AfterEach
public void remigrate() {
    flyway.clean();
    flyway.migrate();
}
```

In log I found only this:

```
2020-06-29 15:20:10.356 DEBUG  [-] 1044 --- [           main] o.f.c.i.s.classpath.ClassPathScanner     : Found resource: db/migration/V0_0_1__database-initialization.sql
2020-06-29 15:20:10.356 DEBUG  [-] 1044 --- [           main] o.f.c.i.s.classpath.ClassPathScanner     : Scanning for classes at classpath:db/migration
2020-06-29 15:20:10.356 DEBUG  [-] 1044 --- [           main] o.f.c.i.c.SqlScriptCallbackFactory       : Scanning for SQL callbacks ...
2020-06-29 15:20:10.356 DEBUG  [-] 1044 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.util.FeatureDetector   : Spring Jdbc available: true
2020-06-29 15:20:10.361 DEBUG  [-] 1044 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbClean        : Cleaning schema "public" ...
```

After this application stuck. When I tried to select flyway history table records, db client is only loading. Selects on other tables works fine, so I expected flyway creates deadlock on history table. Do you have idea how to fix it? Thank you.

Last stacktraces from actuator's threaddump related to flyway's clean:

```
{
methodName: "socketRead0",
fileName: "SocketInputStream.java",
lineNumber: -2,
className: "java.net.SocketInputStream",
nativeMethod: true
},
{
methodName: "socketRead",
fileName: "SocketInputStream.java",
lineNumber: 116,
className: "java.net.SocketInputStream",
nativeMethod: false
},
{
methodName: "read",
fileName: "SocketInputStream.java",
lineNumber: 171,
className: "java.net.SocketInputStream",
nativeMethod: false
},
{
methodName: "read",
fileName: "SocketInputStream.java",
lineNumber: 141,
className: "java.net.SocketInputStream",
nativeMethod: false
},
{
methodName: "readMore",
fileName: "VisibleBufferedInputStream.java",
lineNumber: 140,
className: "org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream",
nativeMethod: false
},
{
methodName: "ensureBytes",
fileName: "VisibleBufferedInputStream.java",
lineNumber: 109,
className: "org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream",
nativeMethod: false
},
{
methodName: "read",
fileName: "VisibleBufferedInputStream.java",
lineNumber: 67,
className: "org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream",
nativeMethod: false
},
{
methodName: "receiveChar",
fileName: "PGStream.java",
lineNumber: 321,
className: "org.postgresql.core.PGStream",
nativeMethod: false
},
{
methodName: "processResults",
fileName: "QueryExecutorImpl.java",
lineNumber: 1978,
className: "org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl",
nativeMethod: false
},
{
methodName: "execute",
fileName: "QueryExecutorImpl.java",
lineNumber: 309,
className: "org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl",
nativeMethod: false
},
{
methodName: "executeInternal",
fileName: "PgStatement.java",
lineNumber: 446,
className: "org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement",
nativeMethod: false
},
{
methodName: "execute",
fileName: "PgStatement.java",
lineNumber: 370,
className: "org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement",
nativeMethod: false
},
{
methodName: "executeWithFlags",
fileName: "PgPreparedStatement.java",
lineNumber: 149,
className: "org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement",
nativeMethod: false
},
{
methodName: "execute",
fileName: "PgPreparedStatement.java",
lineNumber: 138,
className: "org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement",
nativeMethod: false
},
{
methodName: "execute",
fileName: "ProxyPreparedStatement.java",
lineNumber: 44,
className: "com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement",
nativeMethod: false
},
{
methodName: "execute",
fileName: "HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java",
lineNumber: -1,
className: "com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement",
nativeMethod: false
},
{
methodName: "invoke",
fileName: null,
lineNumber: -1,
className: "sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor103",
nativeMethod: false
},
{
methodName: "invoke",
fileName: "DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java",
lineNumber: 43,
className: "sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl",
nativeMethod: false
},
{
methodName: "invoke",
fileName: "Method.java",
lineNumber: 498,
className: "java.lang.reflect.Method",
nativeMethod: false
},
{
methodName: "doExecute",
fileName: "JdbcWrapper.java",
lineNumber: 412,
className: "net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper",
nativeMethod: false
},
{
methodName: "invoke",
fileName: "JdbcWrapper.java",
lineNumber: 137,
className: "net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper$StatementInvocationHandler",
nativeMethod: false
},
{
methodName: "invoke",
fileName: "JdbcWrapper.java",
lineNumber: 294,
className: "net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper$DelegatingInvocationHandler",
nativeMethod: false
},
{
methodName: "execute",
fileName: null,
lineNumber: -1,
className: "com.sun.proxy.$Proxy207",
nativeMethod: false
},
{
methodName: "execute",
fileName: "JdbcTemplate.java",
lineNumber: 215,
className: "org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcTemplate",
nativeMethod: false
},
{
methodName: "doDrop",
fileName: "PostgreSQLTable.java",
lineNumber: 43,
className: "org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.postgresql.PostgreSQLTable",
nativeMethod: false
},
{
methodName: "drop",
fileName: "SchemaObject.java",
lineNumber: 81,
className: "org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.base.SchemaObject",
nativeMethod: false
},
{
methodName: "doClean",
fileName: "PostgreSQLSchema.java",
lineNumber: 97,
className: "org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.postgresql.PostgreSQLSchema",
nativeMethod: false
},
{
methodName: "clean",
fileName: "Schema.java",
lineNumber: 149,
className: "org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.base.Schema",
nativeMethod: false
},
{
methodName: "call",
fileName: "DbClean.java",
lineNumber: 172,
className: "org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbClean$3",
nativeMethod: false
},
{
methodName: "call",
fileName: "DbClean.java",
lineNumber: 169,
className: "org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbClean$3",
nativeMethod: false
},
{
methodName: "execute",
fileName: "TransactionTemplate.java",
lineNumber: 74,
className: "org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.TransactionTemplate",
nativeMethod: false
},
{
methodName: "cleanSchema",
fileName: "DbClean.java",
lineNumber: 169,
className: "org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbClean",
nativeMethod: false
},
{
methodName: "clean",
fileName: "DbClean.java",
lineNumber: 113,
className: "org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbClean",
nativeMethod: false
},
{
methodName: "doClean",
fileName: "Flyway.java",
lineNumber: 1488,
className: "org.flywaydb.core.Flyway",
nativeMethod: false
},
{
methodName: "access$300",
fileName: "Flyway.java",
lineNumber: 85,
className: "org.flywaydb.core.Flyway",
nativeMethod: false
},
{
methodName: "execute",
fileName: "Flyway.java",
lineNumber: 1506,
className: "org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$3",
nativeMethod: false
},
{
methodName: "execute",
fileName: "Flyway.java",
lineNumber: 1499,
className: "org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$3",
nativeMethod: false
},
{
methodName: "execute",
fileName: "Flyway.java",
lineNumber: 1711,
className: "org.flywaydb.core.Flyway",
nativeMethod: false
},
{
methodName: "clean",
fileName: "Flyway.java",
lineNumber: 1499,
className: "org.flywaydb.core.Flyway",
nativeMethod: false
},
```

Comment: Have you tried taking the thread dump and see where exactly it gets stuck?

Comment: @MarkBramnik No, can you tell me please how to do that?

Comment: There are many ways. You can plug tools like JVisualVM or even remote debugger and take the thread dump (in intelliJ its a sign of photo camera in the debugger window). If you don't have an access to these tools, you can use spring boot actuator to generate the thread dump (`/threaddump` endpoint)

Comment: @MarkBramnik i try find out thread dump and I found that some stack trace of thread which executes flyway clean. I added it into question.

Comment: "Cleaning schema "public" ..." is this the correct schema? Postgres docs indicate this is perhaps not the correct schema? see "`5.8.2. The Public Schema`": https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PUBLIC. Check the contents of the `public` schema following `clean()` in your db to confirm its not wiped

Comment: @RobEvans yes we are using default public schema. When clean method executed public schema still contains all objects

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so now you know that its stuck during the JDBC Execution. (I'm adding this as  an answer because its too long for comment, although I admit It probably can't be qualified as a full answer but rather a couple of thoughts aiming to help you sorting these things out):

Anyways, the next step would be understanding what exactly the query was. So please find this out and add to the question

There are many ways to achieve that:

1. Debugging - since thread dump shows exactly on which line the issue is, place a breakpoint and inspect. Yeah, its kind of obvious, but still listing it here since its probably the easiest thing to do.
2. Wrapping the data source with stuff like [log4jdbc](https://code.google.com/archive/p/log4jdbc/wikis/FAQ.wiki)
3. At the level of postgresql:

```
-- show running queries (pre 9.2)
SELECT procpid, age(clock_timestamp(), query_start), usename, current_query 
FROM pg_stat_activity 
WHERE current_query != '<IDLE>' AND current_query NOT ILIKE '%pg_stat_activity%' 
ORDER BY query_start desc;

-- show running queries (9.2)
SELECT pid, age(clock_timestamp(), query_start), usename, query 
FROM pg_stat_activity 
WHERE query != '<IDLE>' AND query NOT ILIKE '%pg_stat_activity%' 
ORDER BY query_start desc;
```

Why doing all this? Because maybe the query gets generated wrong, for example, the name of schema is not specified correctly and so forth, worth checking IMO.

One important thing I would do is to make sure that the test runs against the dedicated database that is not in use by anyone else.

So assuming you've got a real query and see that its good, I would really talk to DBA (well get a suggestion from DBA guys here at least - so consider adding tag of postgresql in the question so that people skillful in Database could monitor the question), because it won't be in java anymore. t can be some kind of locking (there are [ways](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring) to see the locks in postgresql, but it's kind of advanced stuff).

Other than that I would like to mention the following:

1. You've said that you can't rollback the transaction and I kind of took it "for granted". But in PostgreSQL the DDL is also a part of transaction so why actually you can't do that?
2. A couple of years ago when I used PostgreSQL with spring boot, my team back than went for approach based on [Testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/). Basically this allows using the "exclusive" database for the test, and in addition since this solution is dockerized by nature, once the test is done you can restart the docker container and it will be equivalent to cleaning up the database. In my case it wasn't required because, as I mentioned above, we've rolled back all the changes done during the test and it was good enough for our needs.

Comment: Very good advice with select on pg_stat_activity, I found out there is insert select which start before flayway's cleaning. In out integration test we are saving data with spring repository, which will be used for test. This insert of repository blocking flyway, because I tried comment this saving, flyway worked. Do you have idea why this insert isn't finished?

Comment: Hmm, probably you've got into a locking issue here. The insert probably creates some type of lock so flyway with its "cleanup" request gets into this lock and gets stuck because no-one removes this lock. Are you using Spring Data to generate the inserts? If so, how does transaction management work (aren't you bypassing the transaction management of spring in the test)?

Comment: I found problem. In BeforeEach method we were inserting data for tests and in AfterEach cleaning DB with flyway. All these methods obviously were in same transaction which cause deadlock from some reason. I found out it thanks to your advice with pg_stat_activity records so I marked this as answer.